# Calculate code coverage on phpunit test classes

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

We are using phpunit to unit-test our classes like this

```php
namespace VendorName/SystemName {
    final class TestableClass { /** ... */ } 
}

namespace VendorName/SystemName/Tests {
    /**
     * @group unit
     * @covers /VendorName/SystemName/TestableClass
     */
    final class TestableClassTest extends TestCase { /** ... */ }
}
```

When we run these test the `TestableClass` get covered correctly, but we also want to see, whether every line of code in TestableClassTest was actually exectued, as we deal with dead code sometimes like

```php
/**
 * @expectedException /InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function testSomeMethodThrowsException(): void
{
  // do some arrangement

  // call the tested method
  $testable->someMethod();

  // do some post-call assertions
  self::assertBar($baz);
  self::assertFoo($baz);
  // lines above are actually dead code 
  // if test goes right and throws exception
}
```

So we wan't to grab coverage statistics for our tests also.

The straightforward way is to add @covers `/VendorName/SystemName/Tests/TestableClassTest` to each test class, but this requires a lot of manual work.

Is there a correct way to automatically get test cases coverage (maybe listener or config or other phpunit hacks)

Comment: It looks like from your question that when you grep the namespace and the final class name from the test-case you can easily generate the  @covers class-name and just insert it in the comment. Enforcing `forceCoversAnnotation=true`  in the Phpunit XML is an easy check afterwards if the processing did succeed.

Comment: We always have single `@covers` annotation for tested class, so check will show nothing additional. Yes, I think we can do  this programmatically with some kind of "code fixer" tool, but in this case we should maintain these annotations additionally

Comment: Yes, bring 'em in and once complete, it's easier to maintain. Maybe you find something in the Rector or PHP-CS-Fixer projects.